# Card cannot be accessed.Reinsert/change the card or try formatting the card with the camera

Tags: lens

I've been using 32 GB SDHC card on my canon EOS 1100D but one day suddenly it showed "card cannot be accessed.Reinsert/change the card or try formatting the card with the camera.". I tried a 16 GB card but it again showed the message. when I used a 4 GB card it worked perfectly with my camera and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Have you try to format 32GB or 16GB card in camera?

Comment: Have you searched here for the exact same error message?

Comment: [Card cannot be accessed. Reinsert/Change the card or format card with camera](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/85323/card-cannot-be-accessed-reinsert-change-the-card-or-format-card-with-camera)

Comment: [Memory Card Cannot be Accessed](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/48629/memory-card-cannot-be-accessed)

Comment: [Suddenly my camera says “Card cannot be accessed. Reinsert/change the card or format card with camera”](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/81698/suddenly-my-camera-says-card-cannot-be-accessed-reinsert-change-the-card-or-fo)

Answer (score 1):

Reformat the card in the camera.  Usually this happens “suddenly” because either

- the card went bad
- the card was used on the computer and left in a state that the camera doesn’t like.

This action will fix the latter and help verify the former.