# Corrupt SD cards asking to format?

Tags: sdcard

I'm an avid photographer and used bunch of cameras and memory cards that didn't given me any problem like this. Yesterday night when i was transferring files from the SD card to my Laptop, the power supply goes down accidentally and since then, I can't see any of my files stored in there. Moreover, whenever I try to access the stored files, it given me some kind of error messages i.e. Format the drive first!!

I don't know what the hell this is but I need the stored files back. I've found in previous threads that using recovery software could be your last resort. Fortunately, I've found few useful but none of them could actually recover those photos. Stellar Photo Recovery is the tool I've tried to recover photos and luckily, it is showing all my photos there but recovered files can't be open??

If you guys have some better suggestions, please do share it.

P.S. Please, I need the answer immediately or as soon as possible. I've to prepare the presentations for today meeting.

Thanks!!

Comment: the card was corrupted by the laptop crash. You can try recovery, it may or may not work. See http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3323/how-can-i-recover-photo-files-from-a-memory-card-with-a-corrupt-filesystem

Comment: The same I was thinking. However, I can't just leave it simply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the comments on your original question say, the card was likely corrupted when the laptop powered off (which as a side note is why you should safely eject storage or unmount it before you unplug it). It's likely corrupted the file table which is why it wants to format the disk. Once that table is rebuilt you should be able to get the ata back no problems (in theory).

I've used "Getdataback" successfully at work a number of times to recover data off corrupted hard drives, it should work for solid state media too in theory though I have not personally tried. I've recovered data from hard drives, but (touch wood) have not needed to with sdcards or cf cards etc. The concept is the same though.

Don't format the card, you will make it basically impossible to get any data off it without some serious commercial grade software.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Get Data Back also does the same thing. Showing files but I can't just open it after recovery. Perhaps, the originol file is too damaged to be recovered and the software is showing just thumbnail of the files.

Comment: @captainfrey if you shot in raw it might be able to recover the preview jpg not the raw file itself or something. It is sounding like the data itself is corrupt. Maybe try some other recovery tools if you come across any others, you might get lucky. Does the camera read the card still (assuming not). If it does you may be able to copy them via usb rather than using a card reader. Clutching at straws, but it might be worth a shot.