# How do I get my photos off a card with a "card cannot be accessed" error?

Tags: memory-card, canon-600d

Can anyone help me please?

I'm about to use my camera, a Canon 600D, but when I switched on my camera I cannot access any of my photos in my camera. It says "card cannot be accessed."

I tried to access the card on my laptop but it's not reading it, no folder is popping up on my computer.

Is there any possibility of retrieving my photo from my Lexar SD card?

Comment: Did you accidentally lock the card?

Comment: Have you tried ejecting the card and reinserting it? Or trying a separate card reader?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I recover photo files from a memory card with a corrupt filesystem?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3323/how-can-i-recover-photo-files-from-a-memory-card-with-a-corrupt-filesystem)

Comment: when you insert the card into your pc can you open your file explorer and see the sd card? (i.e. does it display a drive letter life E: or F:).

Here is an interesting article that could help as well. http://laithaiphoto.blogspot.com/2012/02/card-cannot-be-accessed-reinsertchange.html

Answer (score 2):

The likely explanation here is that the card has a hardware fault in the SD card which will prevent any attempt to read from it.  If this is the case, your data is likely to be permanently lost.

This is not necessarily 100% certain.  It *could* be filesystem corruption as suggested by mattdm, as that can sometimes manifest itself as the drive not showing in Windows.  One way to tell in Windows is to open Disk Management: in the start menu search for "Disk Management" and the option "Create and format hard disk partitions" will come up.  If you see a listing for your SD card then it's likely that the card is readable, but has filesystem corruption, in which case go ahead and use PhotoRec as suggested elsewhere.  It's worth trying PhotoRec anyway.

However, there is still a real chance that it's a hardware fault with the SD card.

Answer (score 0):

Your card may have dirty contacts.  Clean the contacts with a clean, soft cloth and try again.