# Canon error message: "Card cannot be accessed. Reinsert/Change the card or format card with camera"

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, memory-card, data-corruption

I have a new Canon Rebel T6 and just charged and loaded the battery and then loaded a Lexar 32 GB card. I am getting the following error message:

```
 Card cannot be accessed. Reinsert/change the card or format card with camera
```

Everything is brand new. Can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I recover photo files from a memory card with a corrupt filesystem?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3323/how-can-i-recover-photo-files-from-a-memory-card-with-a-corrupt-filesystem)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't format the card directly in the camera because the camera refuses to recognize it, try formatting it with a computer first. For a 32GB SD card use the FAT32 file system when you format the card.

Then try it in your camera again. If the camera recognizes it the format it again using the camera and you should be ready to shoot!

Comment: It's entirely possible that the _brand new_ SD card is borked out of the box. Attempting to format it in a different device will tell you where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Cannon recommends  formatting new cards, or cards from different cameras. Page 5 in the rebel t6 manual.  Hope this helps. If problem is still there contact cannon support at https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/contactus