# Help recovering Nikon raw files (.nef) from corrupted sd card

Tags: software, memory-card, sdcard, file-recovery

I have come back from a family vacation looking forward to put my hands on this problem: I was shooting with my Nikon D600 camera and a dreadful message showed up (card err). I changed to a different card and had no problem with it for the rest of the trip.

The problematic card is a Kingston 32GB which contains some hundreds of RAW (.NEF) files. I have tried different programs so far without success: Lazesoft, ZAR, PhotoRec, testdisk. Windows sees the drive (e:) but doesn't allow to explore it. Testdisk shows a partition error message. Photorec, after 5 hours hasn't found anything.

This is really desperate, I can't imagine missing those photos. Ideas?

Comment: I had already tried the solutions from the referenced answer and none of them worked. That’s why I have created a new one.

Comment: Possibly related: [Mysteriously lost photos on Nikon D5100 after shooting and plugging into iMac](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/27828/15871)