# Is it possible to make "Protected" the default state for new images on my Nikon D3000?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d3000

I have a Nikon D3000. I want to protect every image that is taken with the camera, but I would like to make this automatically. I mean every time a photo is taken the camera should protect it itself. Is this possible?

Comment: While I don't know about the D3000, I'm not aware of _any_ cameras which have this option. That's strange, now that I think of it, since it'd be so trivial to implement. And it seems like something many people would like. (See [this for example](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14522/are-there-any-cameras-which-require-a-pin-before-deleting-photos).)

Comment: This would be a potentially useful option for any camera, not just the Nikon.

Comment: Maybe this isn't relevant, but if you are using an SD card, you can write protect the card with the physical switch. Of course you can't take new images this way, but maybe that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no such option on D3000.

If you're worried about photos getting deleted by yourself or somebody else, you could try getting your hands on a non-rewritable SD card, like [Sandisk WORM](http://www.electronista.com/articles/10/06/23/sandisk.outs.sd.worm.cards.for.forensics/) or [Toshiba Write-Once](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2011/04/toshiba-announces-write-once-sd-card-film-nerds-rejoice/). Note that you can't reuse those cards after they get full, and you could still lose your pictures if somebody has access to your camera and removes the card.

Another, perhaps more realistic, option for providing protection to your photos is using an Eye-Fi card to instantly upload the photos to network. For this to work, there must be a Wi-Fi network available and accessible at your shooting location.

Comment: The D3000 was almost EOL when the WORM cards came out and there are no firmware upgrades available for that camera, so are you really sure it will work with the WORM card?

Answer (score 2):

I've had a look in the manual (http://www.nikonusa.com/pdf/manuals/noprint/D3000_ENnoprint.pdf (page 100), and it makes no mention of making this the default mode.  Sorry...