# How to restore a backup from a photoshop.com account (possibly with Lightroom)?

Tags: lightroom, sdcard

I have [almost lost](https://superuser.com/questions/389221/what-are-my-best-options-to-recover-data-from-a-faulty-sd-micro-card-used-in-an) some important pics due to a faulty SD card in my wife's phone. She has fixed it by installing (on her phone drive, not on the SD card!) a photoshop express app which was able to read almost all the pics and to upload to a newly created photoshop.com account. Great! (by the way, I would really like to know what's really happened to the SD card, since the app was able to read **almost** all the jpgs which were instead inaccessible by win or linux and both win and linux could read a different subset of the jpgs...Any ideas?)

So now she has on the photoshop account a backup of the pictures, and we are very relieved that they are not lost.

The question is: what is the best way to restore them from the photoshop.com account to my computer? I have a full copy of Lightroom 3 and the beta of Lightroom 4 but if there is any sync option with an online account, it escaped me.

We are talking of about 200 pics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just head to the photoshop.com website, login, select "Organize My Library" from the right side options here:

[image: Step 1]

Then once you are inside of the organizer, you highlight the photos that you want to download (all 200 in your case), then click the Download Zip button:

[image: Step 2]

From that you can download the zip file and extract it to wherever you would like to manage the photos. Then import them into Lightroom and you should be set.

For the piece about recovery, we already have a great question/answer that covers that here:

> [How can I recover deleted photos from an SD Card?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/how-can-i-recover-deleted-photos-from-an-sd-card)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have read it but in my case it didn't work. If you read my question on superuser (linked in the question) you will see that I tried...By the way, thanks for the answer, too! :-)

Comment: Ok, but you didn't say anything about trying out PhotoRec in that Superuser question, which is what I would try, and is suggested in the link that I provided. It is also here: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

Comment: I finally could give a try to PhotoRec. It is really an excellent program but is unable to recover all the jpgs... thanks for mentioning it in any case! BTW the Download zip option is only available to US customers.... I wonder why.