# Possible corrupted files won't open in PS or LR - need to fix them

Tags: nikon, lightroom-3, sdcard, data-corruption, photoshop-cs5

I have a problem just like the post with the link below (I'm having trouble loading any of mine).  The way they look in LR is how it looks on the post below.  They look perfect in Preview mode and then WHAMO ... They suck when opened up.  I'm trouble shooting now per the answers at the below link on this site and the hero hubby is off picking up a new card reader to see if it can magically fix this.  Prayers are being offered up too, because i may need a miracle.  This client flew 5 hours for a beach photoshoot so I can't do a reshoot.  Here's the problem seemingly different from below.  I can't open the NEF files in Photoshop.  When I open the JPG files it only shows the top strip.  When I open in Lightroom I can see the photo, problems and all, but I can't export them.  So I have no way of even trying to fix them since I can't even import them.  You following me so far?  So here's the Q's.  Anyone know how to get these to photoshop so I can fix them? OR Does anyone know someone skilled in photoshop who I can send these to to fix.  AND does anyone know anyone who can pull the corrupted files off the SD card in a way that will save them from ruin (it's a long shot for sure, but doesn't hurt to ask).  I've been digital for 10 years and have never had this problem.  ANY help is most GRATEFULLY appreciated!

[Why do images get "corrupted"?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6045/why-do-my-images-get-distorted-on-my-nikon-dslr)

Comment: Immediately write-protect your card, so you don't accidentally further damage what might be there. Then, try Photorec as recommended in [Is there a way to read or recover corrupted/incomplete photos on CF card?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23065/is-there-a-way-to-read-or-recover-corrupted-incomplete-photos-on-cf-card). (CF and SD are the same, here.)

Comment: It is impossible to answer because we have no idea how corrupted the images are. I could try to convert them by a program line nconvert first to get a usable file. It has *some* chance of working on some of the files. As they say, *it's worth a shot*.

Comment: How did you move the photos from your card to your Hard drive?

Comment: Now the files aren't even showing up on the cards (this happened to two cards at the same time ... LAME! both Lexar pros).

Comment: @Mattdm, We did not write protect them  also (my bad) they are CF cards.  I'll try to google to see what this means.  We tried Image rescue, but will look at Photorec, Thank you!

Comment: @Michael Clark, we opened it and dragged the files to the hard drives.  Thank you!

Comment: The fact that it's both cards at once suggests that it may be the card reader, cable, or computer.

Comment: If the files are not showing up now and they were before, it is possibly a good thing.  Since both cards show the same problem, it is almost certainly NOT the cards.  The problem could have been the camera not writing to the cards, but that would not have changed the visibility after taking it out of the camera.  This leads to either the card reader, computer or (very unlikely) cable being the problem.  The data may still be intact on the cards.  Hopefully the problem wasn't something that caused damage to the cards.

Comment: Have you tried using the camera to transfer the files? Use a different USB port to connect to your computer.

Comment: @mattdm, Update! Encouraged by the suggestions for other recovery software efforts, DH did another scan with the newest version on ImageRescue. That was successful on card A and the files look perfect now. Card B is still a problem.  We've been able to get the files onto the computer however, they are not opening.  Is this something the nconvert might be able to help with?  Would I just convert them to a tiff (currently jpg. and NEF)?

Comment: @AJ Henderson I REALLY hope it's not my camera. THANK YOU!

Comment: @Michael I will also try to transfer from camera if I can get the computer to read the card. We have successfully retrieved card A using data recovery software however card B while now transferred onto the computer they are unreadable.  I REALLY hope it's not my camera. THANK YOU!

Comment: When I accidentally erased an entire hard drive I used Piriform's Recuva. It identified all of my Canon .cr2 files as TIFFs. I used a bulk file renaming tool to change the extensions back to .cr2 and my RAW convertor was able to open them. Recuva is supposed to also be compatible with .nef files. http://www.piriform.com/recuva

Comment: I'll check that out now @Michael Clark.  I think that was the one one the list of programs to check out ... many thanks.  Wow ... an entire hard drive, that's rough.  We had one taken out a few weeks ago when we updated our operating system.  Maybe it would help that too.

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing a data communications issue at some point. When large files are transferred they are broken up into packets and then reassembled. When some of the data is corrupted then the packets don't get reassembled in the correct order, or some of the packets aren't the correct length and so the rendering program thinks bits that are supposed to be telling it one thing are telling it something else because they are the wrong number of positions from the header. I've experienced a couple of routers with memory that started going bad. The first evidence of a problem was when pictures in web pages started getting scrambled exactly the way the examples in the question you linked to were. Why pictures? Because they are often the largest files that make up part of a page. If any portion of the file lands on the bad memory, the whole photo gets corrupted.

In the case of your photos there are several points in the chain that may have caused your files to become corrupted.

- The buffer to memory card transfer
- The memory card to reader transfer
- The reader to RAM transfer
- the RAM to Hard Disk transfer

The further down the chain the problem occurred, the easier it will be to recover.

The first thing to do is to write-protect your memory card. The next thing to do is to take some test shots with a *different* memory card. Do everything else exactly the same to see if the problem reoccurs. If it does, try moving the photos of the test shots using a different method. Instead of a card reader, try to use the camera to do the transfer. Use a USB port that is on a different USB bus than the one your card reader is connected to. (Even internal card readers usually connect to the PCI bus via USB.) If there is one available, see if a different computer can read the card. Change one thing at a time so that you can isolate where the communications problem is.

Comment: Thank you for explaining all of this.  I'll try with the camera next and I'll look up what "write protecting" is.  We are using two different computers with same results and are on card reader #2.  Many THanks!

Comment: If you've changed everything except the card and camera then one of those is most likely where the problem lies. *write protect* is a tab on an SD card and was included before we knew your cards were CF.

Comment: Thank you @Michael Clark.  My husband has been able to recover 2 of the cards now.  Still have one giving us problems :(

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop nor LR can't fix your corrupted data files. They are image processing software. You should refer to [this](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/fix-corrupt-jpeg-photo.html) page, and contact page author, to try to help you (first read the post). Also, try to download JPEGSnoop (a JPEG analysis tool), and try to exam your jpeg pictures. JPEGSnoop will tell you what kind of deformation your JPEG files has, and with that information, we can try to find suitable software which is best in fixing your concrete JPEG file deformation.

If our suggestions do not succeed, you have to call your client, and tell him about your issues. Try to offer him two free photo shooting events, or something else, just to take back his trust.

We are photographers, our job depends on technology, but sometimes something went wrong, and we can't do nothing about it :(

Comment: So true @D4Am.  I think they'll be reasonable about everything I just don't want to have conversations like these :(  I'll look at this JpegSnoop and see it it has any answers.  Many thanks to you!

Comment: Don't let this problem demotivates you. If you were not in this situation these days, you would be once in your carrier. Be patient, we are people, and I'm 100% sure that client will understand your issues :)