# Is there any way to recover photos taken without a memory card?

Tags: nikon, memory-card, file-recovery

I went out today and took over 75 photos with my Nikon Coolpix P100, but I didn't have a memory card in my camera. I'm now unable to retrieve any of the photos - is there any way to recover them?

Comment: is this a joke?

Comment: unfortunately no.  see here: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/35363/how-can-i-retrieve-internal-memory-photos-on-d3100

Comment: As far as I remember, every camera I've used puts up a huge warning on the screen when you take photos without a memory card inserted.  Do Nikon Coolpix cameras not do this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately for you, cameras these days don't come with any form of "internal" memory<sup>1</sup> so if you didn't have a memory card in your camera, your photos are lost forever. Sorry about that.

1. Or if they do, it's so limited that it may as well be none.

Comment: +1 for adding a **footnote** to a one sentence answer plus a heartfelt sorry. :-P :-D

Answer (score 2):

According to the [manual for your camera](http://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/kie88335f7869dfuejdl=-cww2/P100_EN.pdf) it has approximately 43MB of internal storage.

This is unlikely to be able to store the number of pictures you took but, if the instructions in the manual are followed, you may be able to retrieve at least some of the missing pictures.

Page 24 of the manual states that any images on the internal memory can only be accessed if **no memory card is installed**.  So if you installed a card into the camera before trying to retrieve the images, **you will need to remove the card to see if anything was stored in the internal memory**.

Good luck.

Comment: The pdf you are linking is not working, but here is a link that might help. http://www.manualslib.com/manual/111301/Nikon-Coolpix-P100.html?page=127

Comment: weirdly - if you just wait, the manual does eventually appear - and I'd rather leave the link pointing at the Nikon site.