# Corrupted photos

Tags: jpeg, sdhc

Unfortunately SD Card (Kingston 64gb) that I've used in a photoshoot appeared to be faulty and large part of images taken are simply not visible. However I've been able to copy the files from the card.

I've tried a dozen of apps that were promising to recover broken jpgs but failed.

Is there anything else worth to try to recover the photos, or consider them lost forever?

Comment: Which Software did you try?

Comment: Also see [How can I recover photo files from a memory card with a corrupt filesystem?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/3323/1943) and [How can I recover deleted photos from an SD Card?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/1125/1943)

Answer (score 0):

I have had great success in the past with Data Rescue. There website is here...http://www.prosofteng.com/products/data_rescue.php

They offer several different levels of scanning. I had it pull up images I had deleted months previous to a hard drive failure. Amazing that it could still dig them out of the digital gunk. One thing that was interesting though was the older the image the more of if was missing, almost like it had faded.

Anyway, good luck. Sometimes there's no saving it because there's simply nothing to save.

Comment: Hey Rob, this answer is fine, but it doesn't seem to add value over one of the other similar questions that this is really a duplicate of. Do think you could delete this here and repost it on one of the others (like one of the ones linked above)? It's best if we can avoid having helpful information spread across many similar questions. Also, for whatever reason, this type of question seems to be one of the biggest attractors of spammy replies from questionable software vendors, so having the questions consolidated helps protect against that.